# Reset pseudo class changes in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the snippet below I have made the first list item red, and hidden all the other list items.

I am then trying to display all the list items and make them all black by targeting the `li` elements.

Currently, no changes using the last `li` selector are being made.

So, **I'm wondering why the last `li` selector is having no effect on the visual output?**

Thanks

```css
li:not(:first-child) { /* Hide all li elements other than the first one */
  display: none;
}

li:first-child { /* Set list item 1 to be red */
  color: red;
}

/* Undo all changes above */
li { /* Make all li elements have this property ()*/
  display: block;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the last selector in order to obtain the needed result.

Here is an example where all the selectors have the same specificity (class + pseudo-class) and the last one will win:

```css
li:not(:first-child) { /* Hide all li elements other than the first one */
  display: none;
}

li:first-child { /* Set list item 1 to be red */
  color: red;
}

/* Undo all changes above */
li:nth-child(n) { /* Make all li elements have this property ()*/
  display: block;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Do you know why I need to select all nth children? Isn't selecting `li` doing this already?

Comment: @Nick Parsons: As stated, :nth-child() provides the pseudo-class specificity required to match the first two rules. You could replace this with any one other pseudo-class that guarantees a match, such as :not(:root).

Comment: @NickParsons yes `li` is enough and nth-child will add no restriction to the selector, it will simply inclrease the specificty. It has no effect on the selection but only on specificity.

Comment: @NickParsons read the link I shared and you will get more information ;)

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

> This pseudo-class can increase the specificity of a rule. For example,
>   `#foo:not(#bar)` will match the same element as the simpler `#foo`, but has a higher specificity.

Your first rule has more specificity than the last rule, so the `display: none;` stays in effect while `display: block;` is ignored.